# Simple math in python won't work?

Tags: python, math

I just started learning python, and I wrote these three lines of code:

```
points = 49
total = points / 50 * 500 + 40
print "omg wtf ", total
```

And I expected the output to be something like 530, but instead, no matter what I do, I keep getting 40. I tried initializing total to 0, casting the assignment to an int, I threw in a buttload of parentheses, but nothing works. I'm so baffled... Can someone help me / tell me what the heck is going on?

Comment: 49 / 50 is 0, floor division on integers.

Answer (score 7):

"I just started learning Python..." Awesome. I did so myself 1.5 years ago. It's a fun language and a good community.

My **strong** suggestion is that you just switch to `python3`. I'm much happier myself.

In that case you would have seen `530`, just like you expected. In that case, you would have changed  your last line to include parentheses, e.g:

```
print("omg wtf", total)
```

Comment: I upgraded to Python3 8 months ago and STILL have to debug `SyntaxError`s from my slapped-together `print value` statements.

Comment: @TravisGriggs, While a great suggestion, I'd point out that there are many environments where upgrading to 3 is simply not possible

Comment: For the sake of learning @mhlester?

Comment: certainly for the sake of learning in a vacuum use 3. but if for instance OP is learning a different program that uses an embedded python for scripting, you're stuck with whatever it uses

Answer (score 5):

In Python 2, using the division operator `/` on two integers returns an integer by truncating the result.  So `49/50` evaluates to zero.

My recommendation is to always use `from __future__ import division` at the top of every piece of code you write, which removes this confusing behavior.

You can also fix it by using floats, for instance by using `points` be `49.0`, or by doing `total = float(points) / 50 * 500 + 40`.  However, these require you to remember to do that for every calculation.  Because the behavior has been changed in Python 3, the forward-looking way is to use `from __future__ import division` to make float division the default.

Comment: Thanks. Can you refer me to some good python tutorials? The ones I've looked at aren't very descriptive...

Answer (score 2):

Python 2.7 and earlier use integer math when the inputs are integer. so `49 / 50 = 0`. Make one a float to get the output you want:

```
points = 49.  # <-- adding a dot
```

or

```
points = float(49)  # wrapping in float()
```

Now you get:

```
>>> total = points / 50 * 500 + 40
>>> print "omg wtf ", total
530.0
```